# Ionic / Cordova Trying To Learn but Tutorial Build Fails

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am brand new here and just wanted to start with the tutorial. I followed it and here was the results:

> c:\cordova\myApp>ionic -v
>   2.2.1 c:\cordova\myApp>cordova -v
>   6.5.0
>
> c:\cordova>ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 Creating an Ionic
>   2.x app in c:\cordova\MyIonic2Project based on the tutorial template. Downloading:
>   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
>   Downloading:
>   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial/archive/master.
>   zip Installing npm packages (may take a minute or two)...
>   - ? ♫ ? ♫ Your Ionic app is ready to go! ? ♫ ? ♫
>
> Some helpful tips:
>
> Run your app in the browser (great for initial development):  ionic
>   serve
>
> Run on a device or simulator:  ionic run ios[android,browser]
>
> Share your app with testers, and test on device easily with the Ionic
>   View compa nion app: http://view.ionic.io
>
> c:\cordova\MyIonic2Project>cordova platform add android Adding android
>   project... Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:  Path:
>   platforms\android  Package: com.ionicframework.myionic2project595383 
>   Name: MyIonic2Project  Activity: MainActivity  Android target:
>   android-25 Subproject Path: CordovaLib Android project created with
>   cordova-android@6.1.2 Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
>              This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android gr
>
> eater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do not
>   need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
>
> Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android
>
> c:\cordova\MyIonic2Project>ionic run android
>
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build c:\cordova\MyIonic2Project
>   ionic-app-scripts build
>
> [10:11:33] ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0 [10:11:33] build dev started ...
>   [10:11:33] clean started ... [10:11:33] clean finished in 10 ms
>   [10:11:33] copy started ... [10:11:33] transpile started ...
>   [10:11:36] transpile finished in 3.84 s [10:11:36] webpack started ...
>   [10:11:37] copy finished in 4.18 s [10:11:45] webpack finished in 8.85
>   s [10:11:45] sass started ... [10:11:46] sass finished in 1.01 s
>   [10:11:46] build dev finished in 13.74 s
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ashworta\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
>
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>
> Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be
>   faster).
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. •
>
> •Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 37.257 secs

So this tutorial project runs in browser but not on Android. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using proxy?

Comment: I am using a proxy.  What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Can you run `ionic run android` without proxy?

Comment: @tashworth19191 try running the build with --info or --debug option to get more details on error

Comment: My problems with running Ionic apps on Android usually stem from permissions issues within the `/platforms/android` folder. Running `cordova build android --debug` is usually helpful.